# change main wrapper background color with CSS button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to change background color of main wrapper using the `background-color` attribute via CSS button

My class is `<div class='mainWrapper fullWidth'>`  the CSS for the class is `.mainWrapper`

Below is the CSS for the button I found it at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>


<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried the following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>




<style>
    body {
        background: grey;
    }
</style>

<script>
        function colorize(light) {
            if (light) {
                
                document.body.style.background = 'grey';
            }
            else {
               
                document.body.style.background = 'blue';
            }
        }
    </script>

<body>
    <div id="switch">
       
        <button id="slider round" onclick="colorize(true)"></button>
      
        <div id="slider">
            <button onclick="colorize(false)"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this code works, what do you want eaxactly?

Comment: It looks like it should be a slider that determines the background color, if I understand the html correctly

Comment: @hamid I want to change background color of main wrapper using the background-color attribute via CSS button My class is <div class='mainWrapper fullWidth'> the CSS for the class is .mainWrapper the CSS for the button I found it at w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch I want to modfiy it so that it works with my class , Again My class is <div class='mainWrapper fullWidth'> the CSS for the class is .mainWrapper

Comment: @Coss no I want to change background color of main wrapper using the background-color attribute via CSS button My class is <div class='mainWrapper fullWidth'> the CSS for the class is .mainWrapper the CSS for the button I found it at w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch I want to modfiy it so that it works with my class , Again My class is <div class='mainWrapper fullWidth'> the CSS for the class is .mainWrapper

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the background color with the toggle switch?
If so you can add an event listener to the checkbox and change the background of your wrapper div/class using javascript or jQuery.
Here is an example of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/ba513j27/

```
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="tog-bg">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("tog-bg").addEventListener('change', function(){
        if(document.getElementById("tog-bg").checked) {
            document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundColor = "white";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
      });
      
    </script>
```

Comment: thats what I need but When I applied it to my site it doesn't work I want to change background color of main wrapper using the `background-color` attribute via CSS button

My class is `<div class='mainWrapper fullWidth'>`  the CSS for the class is `.mainWrapper`

 the CSS for the button I found it at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch  I want  to modfiy it so that it works with my class , Again My class is `<div class='mainWrapper fullWidth'>`  the CSS for the class is `.mainWrapper`

Comment: In that case, you can access all the contents that are using a certain class using `document.getElementsByClassName('your-class-name-here')`. Note that this will return a collection of objects. Here is an example and I do hope this answers your question. [example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x24ydtpf/)

Answer (score 0):

Select DOM elements using the class name, then add any color that you want

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper").style.backgroundColor = "Color Name";
```

Comment: thats what I need but When I applied it to my site it doesn't work I want to change background color of main wrapper using the `background-color` attribute via CSS button

My class is `<div class='mainWrapper fullWidth'>`  the CSS for the class is `.mainWrapper`

 the CSS for the button I found it at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch  I want  to modfiy it so that it works with my class , Again My class is `<div class='mainWrapper fullWidth'>`  the CSS for the class is `.mainWrapper`